# Problem inserting a figure in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, floats

I am writing a research paper using LaTeX.

I have certain images to insert. Now when we observe the images from the research paper, they have the following format:

```
    image
    its caption
```

I am trying to replicate this using the following code

```
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{E:/Arifah/MS/thesis/final thesis report/Component           Based Software Development.png} 
    \caption{Component Based Software Development}
    \end{figure}
```

However, the format that I am getting is

```
    the path of image
    image
    caption
```

Now, how do I remove the path?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748117/inserting-a-figure-in-latex?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, even though this question already has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your filename contains spaces which LaTeX cannot handle.

Either renamce your file to not contain spaces, or if you run `pdflatex` try the [grffile](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/grffile) package which should make it work even with spaces.

Comment: i renamed the file n now used the following code........ \begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{E:/Arifah/MS/thesis/final thesis report/ComponentBasedSoftwareDevelopment.png} 
\caption{Component Based Software Development}
\end{figure}............

Comment: it gives the same result i.e my path is being displayed

Comment: @ArifahAzhar: There's still a space in `../final thesis report/..`.

Comment: seems like i had to remove all the spaces in my path....thanx loads for the help

Comment: Removing spaces in your path isn’t a good solution – you are destroying your paths! A better solution is to use relative instead of absolute image paths. Works perfectly. Or, if those paths still contain spaces, set up a base path for your graphics using the options of the `graphics` package, and escape the spaces … the documentation of the package contains clues, if I remember correctly.

Comment: i will def c that

Comment: @Konrad: Nobody said mutilating paths was the solution here. But I 100% agree, using relative paths (preferably in some limited directory) is always the best solution since the document becomes standalone and can be distributed or compiled elsewhere.

Comment: @honk Oh, I wasn’t criticising your answer. It’s just that “mutilating paths” often seems like the easiest way out of this dilemma (see Arifah’s first comment).

Comment: depending on your operating system, you might be able to define symbolic links which do not contain spaces. E.g. with Linux, `ln -s PathToGraphicsDirectory MyGraphics` and you could then use `\graphicspath{MyGraphics}` in your LaTeX file